# What format is xlc debug info?

Tags: aix, dwarf, xlc

I'm trying to look at the debug info for a program compiled with xlc v11.1 on AIX. I used `-g` flag when compiled, but looking at the help page I don't see it mention DWARF anywhere or if I can specify what format I want. Any ideas how I can tell what format is being used or any tools that can tell me?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default debug info on AIX was **stabstring**.

See https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_aix_71/filesreference/XCOFF.html#XCOFF__jtsci131jbau for the detail spec.

XLC V11 is very old. If you upgrade the compiler to newer one, you may have choices to switch to use dwarf.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGH3R_16.1.0/com.ibm.xlcpp161.aix.doc/compiler_ref/opt_dbgfmt.html

Comment: Is there a tool like dwarfdump to view stabstring info?